# Styling Special Letters

Tags: html, css, fonts, styling

I have set a global font family for my project which is from Google Fonts. It is called Gothic A1. But I am having an issues when I use characters such as 'ã', 'í', etc. The picture posted demonstates that. What must I do to fix it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix this issue is to choose a different font. Taking a look at the Google Fonts page, you can see that the font doesn't support those special characters, so the browser is rendering them in the default font, which is why it appears different:

[image: characters not supported]